# Convert this code in c# for decode bmp file

Tags: c#

Please convert the code in c# or vb I'm using hdr photography in my C# project, but I cannot convert this code in c++ to C#.

#include "define.h"

```
void bmp_read(char *filename, bmp *b)
{
    FILE *input = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(input == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    fread(&b->header.type, 2, 1, input);
    fread(&b->header.size, 4, 1, input);
    fread(&b->header.reserved1, 2, 1, input);
    fread(&b->header.reserved2, 2, 1, input);
    fread(&b->header.offset, 4, 1, input);

    fread(&b->info.size, 4, 1, input);
    fread(&b->info.width, 4, 1, input);
    fread(&b->info.height, 4, 1, input);
    fread(&b->info.planes, 2, 1, input);
    fread(&b->info.bits, 2, 1, input);
    fread(&b->info.compression, 4, 1, input);
    fread(&b->info.imagesize, 4, 1, input);
    fread(&b->info.xresolution, 4, 1, input);
    fread(&b->info.yresolution, 4, 1, input);
    fread(&b->info.ncolours, 4, 1, input);
    fread(&b->info.importantcolours, 4, 1, input);

    b->info.imagesize   = b->info.width * b->info.height * 3;
    b->data             = new unsigned char [b->info.imagesize];
    fread(b->data, b->info.imagesize, 1, input);

    fclose(input);
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not code conversion service.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free human code translation service. Please try this yourself and come back when you have a specific question about code you've written.

Comment: If only life were this easy I'd never need to write another line of code in my life.

Comment: You are trying it again? In previous question you got explanation of stackoverflow rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a default definition for "BMP" structure (as it is in this code). First and most importnant question is: what do you will make with the bmp file?

It is something you can not do with the function "Image.FromFile" function?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx